# Where to find the Application Loader in Xcode 7.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

When I upload through Xcode, it always showed errors, so I searched google for answers and found the link about [Ways to upload built App](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/UsingApplicationLoader.pdf). The document mentioned to use Application Loader to upload. But
where is "Application Loader" located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

select **XCode** menu --> **Open Developer tool** -> **Application loader**

[image]

Comment: Now I find it. Thanks alot. But how did you firstly know this?

Comment: @BruceJordanWang -- good question bro. really appreciate , my senior told on once up on a time,

Comment: @BruceJordanWang -- if my answer is useful give the tick mark it is useful in future

Comment: Thanks. You mentioned "give the tick mark ", do you mean to upvote? I'm not allowed to do that because of the low reputation.